# Django: IntegrityError null value violates not-null constraint

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In my django app, there is something strange that's happening & i'm not understanding.

I have two different tables (**employeeProfile** & **purchaserShippingDetail**) each has a field with the relation  `OneToOneField` but with the 1st table (**employeeProfile**) in the field *user* that uses OneToOneField i can pass a string representation say *Michael* using api & i don't get an error but in my 2nd table that has similar structure when i add a string representation to i get

> IntegrityError at /api/clients/shipping/
> null value in column "owner_id" violates not-null constraint

1st Table model (works fine)

```
class employeeProfile(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png',upload_to='employee_photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="employee_profile")
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.name
```

2nd Table Model (*The one that throws the "owner_id" violates not-null constraint error*)

```
class purchaserShippingDetail(models.Model):

    frequent_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    owner = models.OneToOneField(Purchaser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="purchaser_shipping")
    address = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.owner.name
```

**Purchaser** Model

```
class Purchaser(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True)
    data_added = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializer for **purchaserShippingDetail** model

```
class purchaserShippingDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = purchaserShippingDetail
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Views.py** for purchaserShippingDetail model

```
class purchaserShippingDetailsListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = purchaserShippingDetailSerializer
    queryset = purchaserShippingDetail.objects.all()
```

**EDIT:** Added Purchaser model table

Comment: if owner can be null set `owner = models.OneToOneField(Purchaser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name=purchaser_shipping, blank=True, null=True)` else you might have forgot to pass owner_id (integer) while making request.

Comment: After setting to null, the request is passed but instead of using the provided name, say ``Michael``, it uses null. On your 2nd point, i'm trying to avoid passing owner_id  since in the front-end, someone may not know all the owner_id of all purchasers instead they want to use the name of the purchaser

Comment: I think you must pass owner_id, that is how one purchaseShippingDetail table recognizes your  Purchaser table. I mean with primary key which is id not owner name. In your case you can set owner name to be pk I guess but it must be unique.
PS: Use UpperCamelCase convention while naming your class for good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post the `Purchaser` model as well? There is a referenced field `owner_id` that we can't see in your post, which will explain more.

Have you added the owner field in a recent migration? It could be that you are adding a non-nullable field to a Table with existing rows, making those rows fail to satisfy the non-nullable condition.

You cannot add a default value on a OneToOneField so in that case you have to first add the field as `null=True`.
Then create an empty migration file to instantiate all rows on that table so no rows have a null value. Normally you do this by `manage.py makemigrations app_name --empty`.

That file could look something like

```py
from django.db import migrations

def instantiate_owner(apps, schema_editor):
    purchaserShippingDetail = apps.get_model("appname", "purchaserShippingDetail")
    Purchaser = apps.get_model("some_other_app", "Purchaser")

    for detail in purchaserShippingDetail.objects.all():
      owner = Purchaser.objects.get(some_unique_criteria=detail.unique_criteria)
      detail.owner = owner
      detail.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
       ...,
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(instantiate_owner),
    ]
```

After that is complete you can remove the `null=True` in your model and make another migration.

Comment: Sorry about that, i have updated the code to include the model. Also, i don't have any ``owner_id`` field, just the ``owner`` which has the OneToOneField. I'm assuming postgres automatically add the ``owner_id`` field

Comment: You could try
`owner = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='owner.name', read_only=True)`

If that doesn't work, can you post the migration files for the api app.

Comment: It didn't work. I was thinking of altering my  **views.py** by adding ```def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.instance.owner_id = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        serializer.save()``` but the problem i'm having is getting the instance of **Purchaser**

Comment: I don't know why you are avoiding talking about the migrations files.
It is important for us to know in which order you have added fields and table rows.

If you have added the purchaserShippingDetail model after Purchaser you cannot satisfy the not null-constraint.
The solution for that is in my original answer.

If your serializer was the problem it would give you `ValidationError`, not `IntegrityError`.

Comment: I created a new app(without making any migrations), the way i ordered my models was 1st the **Purchaser** model followed by **purchaserShippingDetail**, set up the serializers after finishing everything i made the migrations. Thus the error.